# Replacing Capacitors in HVAC Condensor

Tags: hvac

The fan on the outside condensor of my HVAC system stopped spinning.  If I give it a push it starts up.  My understanding is that this typically is just the capacitor going bad and is a relatively simple replacement fix.

The old capacitors (there are two of them in there) read:

- Packard Inc. Stock #, POC5, 5MFD +- 5%, 370VAC 50/60 HZ
- First Choice, Y4606-vi, 50uF +-5%, 440VAC 50/60HZ

I can't find the exact same replacements on line, but I assume all I need to do is match the MFD and VAC numbers on the replacement capacitors?

Comment: You also need to consider how it's wired in -- how many connectors per, etc.

Comment: The capacitors are both run capacitors, i.e., they both only have two connections... As far as I can tell, the fins are identical and aren't labeled differently. I assume since it's only two wires, it doesn't matter which wire goes to which fin?

Comment: By matching the MFD 5 micro farad and the voltage 370 or greater you will be fine. 50MFD is two large. if you cannot find a 5MFD cap stay below 10 MFD or the phase shift may be two large 4.7 is a common value that also would work.

Comment: Thanks Ed. The 50MFD capacitor is for the compressor (I believe). I think it still works since once I get the fan spinning the system blows cold air.  I was planning on replacing this one anyway since it looks old.  This one also only has two terminals, I assume it doesn't matter which wire goes to which terminal?

Comment: I have replaced capacitors in both my condenser and HVAC. The purpose of the run capacitor is to basically get two-phase from single-phase AC. The delayed AC through the capacitor is fed to a second set of windings in the motor. As long as you stay within the tolerances of the original capacitor, you will be fine. That is to say, you have a 5 MFD capacitor that is 5%, so your tolerance is 4.75 - 5.25 MFD. However, you want the tolerance of the replacement to stay within that range, so a 4.7 MFD would have to have near 0% tolerance. Any brand will do.